# Project allocation

Tags: algorithm

Hello I'm doing my final year project based on the title 'Project Allocation and Monitoring'.
I'm stuck with the algorithm. I need to come up with an algorithm to allocate the projects to student firstly over preference and if there are any clashes, then checking the CPA of students.

Answer (score 0):

You should check **stable matchings** and **bipartite graphs** on the web.